# TextToSpeech data download

Tags: java, android, android-intent, download, text-to-speech

The code bellow is used for install the TTS data.

```
Intent installIntent = new Intent();
installIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
startActivity(installIntent);
```

Some questions:

- This code is used for install all data for all TTS plugins installed in the device?
- This code is used for install data for all languages? How can I specify the language for data download?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the language as follow

```
Intent installIntent = new Intent();
installIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);    
ArrayList<String> languages = new ArrayList<String>();
languages.add("it-IT"); // for example this will install Italian language
installIntent.putStringArrayListExtra(TextToSpeech.Engine.EXTRA_CHECK_VOICE_DATA_FOR, 
                                                languages);
startActivity(installIntent);
```